# ElasticSearch is missing some columns in between Indexing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Hi I have a problem I have a table user with (id, name, address and email), My elasticsearch memory is 256mb .When i am indexing data it missing some columns data in indexing process. Missing data may be email or any other fields please some one tell me why elasticsearh is missing data.

```
elasticsearch version -> 0.90


      indexes :book_info do
        indexes :isbn, :type => 'string'
        indexes :isbn13, :type => 'string'
        indexes :description, :type => 'string'
        indexes :release_date, type: 'date'
        # commenting all the code related to plan type in elastic search
        indexes :plan_type, :type => 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
        indexes :is_available, :type => 'boolean'
      end
```

Sample data save in elasticsearch like this

```
book_info: {
isbn: 62010662
isbn13: 9780062010667
description: <p><em>Scambusters!</em> is a working manual senior citizens can use to defend themselves against the most common scams aimed at the elderly. It provides readers with a comprehensive approach to identifying scams in the making, and shows them specific prevention tools and how to use them. </p><p>Inside, you'll find step-by-step instructions, helpful anecdotes, and references to dozens of consumer organizationals and government agencies devoted to thwarting swindlers. Weather buying mutual funds, repairing a car, purchasing drugs from online pharmacies, or taking out loans on your home, <em>Scambusters!</em> will protect seniors when they need it.</p>
release_date: 2010-05-25T00:00:00Z
plan_type: null
is_available: true
}
```

Comment: you will need to share a lot more information if we are going to help at all. It would be very helpful to see the schema, sample data, number of documents, code snippet, Elasticsearch version, etc.

Comment: @JohnPetrone sir i updated my question please check now